# HTML Table pagination issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc, html-table

I am facing an issue with HTML table pagination. Am appending items to table. for each row the first td is checkbox and last td is input by default it's disabled. By clicking on checkbox on each td am enabling the input type. It's working fine on first page. but it's not working from 2nd page.

Below is my code to enable input on checkbox selection.

```
$('input[type=checkbox]').on('click', function () {
        debugger;
        var isChecked = $(this).is(':checked');

        $(this).parent().parent().find('input[type="text"]').attr('disabled', !isChecked);
    });
```

Any thoughts/help Please?

Comment: You need to use event delegation - `$('#InventoryTable tbody').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() { .... });` assuming the `<tbody>` element exists when the pages is first rendered and is not replaced

Comment: stepehn thanks for your comment. still am facing the same issue.

Comment: Does that element exist? You have not shown the relevant code so I can only guess. Just use `$(document).on('click', 'input[type="checkbo‌​x"]', function() { .... });` (and then later replace `document` with the closest ancestor which exists)

Comment: Stephen.. Sorry i have posted wrong code. I am using another piece of code to enable the textbox based on checkbox. Edited the question.

Comment: That makes no difference. You dynamically adding the table rows, so you need to use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/)